# Clio API v4; Endpoint for getting list of documents within one folder

Tags: clio-api

Problem: Getting a list of documents that exist in a specific folder

Tried solution:

- endpoint `/api/v4/folders/list.json` seems to be working exactly the same as `/api/v4/folders.json`
- Something similar to this [image] - similar endpoint doesn't seem to exist
- Filtering documents by parent_id, however this functionality doesn't exist

Is there some kind of example of the endpoint to perform such operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation, it appears as though /api/v4/folders/list.json returns the contents of a folder.  If you are trying to get a list of all the documents within the folder 1425540709 (using your example above) then your GET would add a parameter "parent_id = 1425540709".  According to the documentation, if you don't send a "parent_id" it defaults to the root folder for the account.

Your request url should look like this I believe:

`https://app.goclio.com/api/v4/folders/list.json?parent_id=1425540709&limit=25`

The response will be a json array of the items within that folder.

Make sure you send it a parameter for what fields you want back too because otherwise the api defaults to just id and etag.